# Какую структуру хранения выбрать для списка классов Bootstrap

Tags: c#, классы, vb.net, структуры-данных

Имеется список классов Bootstrap, необходимо каким то образом описать их, например в виде `Enum` или в виде класса со свойствами или еще как то, чтобы к именам этих классов было удобно обращаться при проектировании приложения.

Например если описать все возможные имена классов в `Enum`, то как сгруппировать их, что бы можно было работать не со всем списком а группами.

Например есть скласс `btn`, а так же применяемые вместе с ним `btn-default`, `btn-primary` и т.д. По идее `btn` можно взять как имя группы в данном случае.

> P.S. Речь идет про использование intellisense